# JQuery Resizable Draggable Position Absolute

Tags: jquery, position, draggable, absolute, resizable

Take a look at this -> http://jsfiddle.net/Zj23S/1/

I am using resizable and draggable. The problem I am facing is with draggable. I cannot seem to drag outside of the div, probably because I set div.position = absolute. If I take this away my resizing moves the other elements, which I do not want. How can I drag the element anywhere on the screen while maintaining position absolute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this I think it will help you.

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqDnR/

or if you want jQuery UI:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/01/jquery-resizable-draggable-resize-drag-tutorial-example.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, the problem still remains. In the dev.iceburg link notice that when you drag and resize the box, the div that you dragged from will also resize. I don't want anything else except the object being resized to resize.

Comment: The second link (viralpatel) does not include any examples with multiple elements. It's just one box. The problem exists when dragging and resizing with other elements around. Nothing else should move when resizing :)

Comment: Well if other elements shouldn't move then you need to play with css a little bit, positioning them and so on, it depends of your elements.
I've done this but everything in the div needed to be moved together.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you wanted?
http://jsfiddle.net/Zj23S/15/

Comment: that's still `position: relative;`

Answer (score 3):

it's a problem in resizable:

```
(f.is(".ui-draggable")||/absolute/.test(f.css("position")))&&f.css({position:"absolute",top:e.top,left:e.left})
```

So, the only thing you should do is removing class .ui-draggable and all will be OK, because the check will fail if start position of the elements was relative.

You can do it by adding

```
{... addClasses: false ...}
```

setting in your draggable options